# Название алгоритма ML

Tags: алгоритм, машинное-обучение

Задача: в n-мерном пространстве есть множество векторов (пускай от все координаты будут от 0 до 1) и есть точка в этом пространстве. Нужно найти какую-то линейную комбинацию векторов, чтобы они в сумме (с коэффициентами) приходили в данную точку. При этом желательно чтобы количество взятых векторов было минимальным.
Также было бы неплохо иметь возможность выдать векторам приоритеты (числа от 0 до 1), чтобы преимущественно использовались вектора с более высоким приоритетом.
Я знаю, как решить эту задачу при помощи генетического алгоритма, но они довольно медленно работают. Может быть, это какая-то классическая задача в машинном обучении, у которой есть свое название?

Comment: *Может быть, это какая-то классическая задача, у которой есть свое название?* Решение системы линейных уравнений (СЛАУ). Если количество (непараллельных и ненулевых) векторов меньше мерности пространства - решения может и не существовать. Если равно - решение единственное. Иначе решений овердохрена, а оптимальное можно найти скорее всего лишь переборно.

Comment: Если приоритеты векторов, важнее общего количества, то пробуешь добавляешь вектора в коллекцию по одному, в порядке убывания приоритетов. Если новый вектор линейно зависим  с векторами уже включенными в коллекцию, то не добавляешь. Если искомый вектор линейно зависим векторам коллекции - значит решение нашли.

Comment: Тут подход со СЛАУ или что-то подобное не подойдет. Я не просто так уточнил, что алгоритм нужен мл-ный. n порядка 10-15, а количество векторов - несколько тысяч

Comment: А координаты векторов, случайно, не рациональные дроби (или даже целые числа)? Просто искать точное соответствие векторов и их линейных комбинаций в действительных числах - очень подозрительно.

Comment: За линейное время от числа векторов строится матрица полного ранга, обращается, умножается на вектор. Решение готово. Сложность *O(NK^2)*, где - *N* - число векторов, *K* - размерность. Если надо меньше *K*, надо думать.

Comment: Почитайте про метод главных компонент (PCA). Там решают задачу как из тысяч векторов оставить только K.

Comment: @Chorkov, да, в задаче допускается небольшое отклонение результата от данной точки. Например, на какое-то константное расстояние

Comment: Насчёт минимизации количества векторов почитайте про регуляризацию. Только я не помню которая за этот вариант отвечает L1 или L2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хороших ответов не нашел, но кроме почти тривиального генетического алгоритма можно попробовать сиплекс-метод. Он работает куда быстрее генетика, но и не гарантирует хороший результат. Буду проводить эксперименты.